# Why doesn't chaining Model queries / assignments work in rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How come this works in the rails console:

```
foo = Ad.find(2)
foo.user = User.find(1)
foo.user # => #<User id: 1, name: "john">
```

But this doesn't?

```
Ad.find(2).user = User.find(1)
Ad.find(2).user  # => nil
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because each time you write `Ad.find(2)` it is returning a new instance of the `Ad` class whose ID is 2, and your code is changing the associated User on that instance but **never saving the change**. So in this line:

```
Ad.find(2).user = User.find(1)
```

you fetch an instance of Ad with ID 2, set that instance's `user` association to `User.find(1)`, but this change is never saved to the database, and is lost once the statement ends. In the next line:

```
Ad.find(2).user  # => nil
```

you are just fetching another instance of Ad with ID 2, but since the previous change was never persisted to the DB, `user` is `nil`.

Like you showed in the first code snippet, you must use a local variable to temporarily keep a reference to your Ad instance in order to call `.save` on it, in order to persist to the DB. This should work:

```
foo = Ad.find(2)
foo.user = User.find(1)
foo.save
Ad.find(2).user  # => #<User id: 1>
```

Comment: Just checked on my sample app. It has `Employee` and `Skill` with HABTM relations to each other. If I do in rails console `Employee.find(1).skills << Skill.find(3)` it adds new skill to employee. So when I enter `Employee.find(1).skills` the skill with id = 3 is in the list.

Comment: Yes but in that case you're using `.skills << Skill.find(3)`, i.e. you're adding a new record to a has_many or HABTM relationship, and Rails fires the DB update immediately in that case (see "[collection<<(object, …)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many)" section of `has_many` docs). For single-record associations (like the `.user` example above), it is deferred until a `.save` or similar.